# Swift performance segue and navigation Controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, segue

I have 2 independent viewControllers.

In the first I have a tableView with a navigation controller, when I click on the cell, it opens a detail viewController.

in the second VC, I perform several operations where at the end I visualize a button if if clicked I have to open the detail viewController.

with a `performSegue (withIdentifier: "towardsDetailsProfile", sender: nil)`

It works but it does not appear in the navigation controller.

Is it possible to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your view controller should be child of a navigation controller. You can do that by selecting the second view controller (the one with the button) and clicking on "Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller".

Comment: ok thanks, the seocod view controller is already a child of a view controller if I come from promo VC of course the navigation controller it is displayed if I instead come from the external button it is not seen.

is there a way to make the 2 VC navigation controller appear when I arrive from the external button?